# SwiftUI How to change Value in for Loop

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am currently developing a food ordering app.
I have come to following problem.
here is part of the relevant code

[I have a button at the top right to change enum Foodstage to .main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD1S5.jpg)

````
@Published var cartexpress : [CartModel] = [] 

 enum Foodstage : Codable,CaseIterable {
    case Starter,Second, Main,SpecialMenu,Drinks, Extra
}


struct CartModel : Codable,Identifiable,Equatable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name : String
    var quantity : Int
    var price : Double
    var type : Foodstage
    var date: Date
    var extra : [String]
} ```


the error appears when I want to use for In loop to the the Food Stage
``` func CookTogether(){
        
        cartexpress.forEach { type in
            return type.type = .Main
        }
        
    }
````

the error code is **Cannot assign to property: 'type' is a 'let' constant.**

please can anyone teach me how to fix this issue.
many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `forEach`, you are creating a new variable - `type`. However, this is constant, and `CartModel` is a `struct`, meaning that we can't just change the properties as it's not a reference type.

What you can do is iterate over the indices of `cartexpress` (similar to `0 ..< cartexpress.count`) and set the `type` property for each element in the array.

Try the following code:

```
for index in cartexpress.indices {
    cartexpress[index].type = .main
}
```

*I used `.main` as my enum case name, rather than `.Main`, by convention.*